# Is there a way to disable Android's status bar?

Tags: android, tasker

I want to build my own status bar using Tasker. Is it possible to disable the Android status bar completely? I'm currently running Android 7.0 on my Galaxy S6. Before this phone I had a rooted HTC M7 running CyanogenMod and that allowed me to at least hide the status bar, but it still appeared when I swiped down from the top of the screen and also when I had a keyboard open.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to hide status bar
add these lines in onCreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```